# Dagger2 : Field Injection which also has injection field in it

Tags: java, dependency-injection, field, dagger-2

I am trying to learn Dagger2.
While I was practicing, I had a question.

My Question is
In short, I want to do field Injection which also has field injection in it.
How to make or use component?

I will explain my question below with my code.
below code works fine but I want better? or beautiful code.

**Person.java** <- this class has field injection.

```
public class Person {

public String name;
public int age;

@Inject
public Company involvedCompany; // Look here!! has field Injection.

public Person(String name, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "[User] name : " + name + ", age : " + age + ", Company : " + involvedCompany.toString();
}
}
```

***TestPerson.java***

```
public class TestPerson {

@Inject
Person person; //I want to do field injection to this field. 
               //this filed also contains field injection in it. 
               //(See previos code Person.java)

TestPersonComponent component;

private TestPerson(){
    component = DaggerTestPersonComponent.builder()
            .companyModule(new CompanyModule("Tmax", "Korea"))
            .personModule(new PersonModule("Ui-Gyun", 28))
            .build();

/****************************************************
 HERE!!!  I am wondering How to change under code!!
*****************************************************/
    component.inject(this);  // for this class.
    component.inject(person); // for person's inside field.
}

public void call(){
    System.out.println(person.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    TestPerson test = new TestPerson(); 
    test.call();
}
}
```

***TestPersonComponent.java***

```
@Component(modules={CompanyModule.class, PersonModule.class})
public interface TestPersonComponent {

void inject(TestPerson test);
void inject(Person person);

}
```

I omit Company.java CompanyModule.java, PersonModule.java.

This is simple example.
but in bigger project, there will be very complex and many injections in it.

In that case making Component.java and call inject() method like upper code is really bothering and hard to code.
Is there any good way to code beautiful?

Comment: What exactly is bothering you with your sample injection?

Comment: What I want is... I want to erase component.inject(person)  which is in TestPerson.java

Comment: If I erase component.inject(person) in TestPerson.java, there would be null value in person.company. 

Is there any good Idea? when I inject value to person at TestPerson.java, person's injection field(company) is injected automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could explicitly define the connection between both instances (Company and Person) and pass the needed company to the person inside the person's constructor. The way to go here would be to define this dependency inside your PersonModule, since Dagger2 can look up dependencies throughout different modules. This could look something like this:

```
@Module
public class PersonModule {
..
@Provides
public Person providePerson(Company company){
  return new Person(..,..,company);
}
..
}
```

This way you only need to call inject method once for the Person instance of the TestPerson class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have question.
You mean I should pass company Object through Person's constructor.
In that case, how company is injected to field in person, without assigning in constructor?

Comment: The company won't be injected by the annotation but instead by its constructor. Of course you need to assign it in the constructor.

Comment: The scope of the dependency injection with annotations is only the class, which is defined in the component method. Nested injection annotation are simply not in the current scope of dagger, since this would bring up a lot of complications and questions. For now you should just do it via the objects constructor.